# How close the alert when I click on the button "Yes"

Tags: android, alert, android-alertdialog

I´m trying to close an alert when I click on the "Yes" button. The button interface executes a process during 10 seconds aprox. I would like to close the alert dialog when I click on the button because the alert is closed only when the SaveRoute method is finished. My code:

```
imageRouteDetSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {

        //** Save the current route             
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                         MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this).create();
                                    alertDialog.setTitle("Saving...");
                                    alertDialog.setMessage("......");
                                    alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                                          alertDialog.dismiss(); //-- No close the dialog
                                          SaveRoute();//-- Big proccess

                                       }
                                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `alertDialog.dismiss();` try using `dialog.dismiss();`

Moreover 'Big proccess' is better not to run on UI thread, because they block the UI.

AsyncTask example doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Do you recommend me to call the 'Big process' on a new thread?

Comment: at 4+ devices some long tasks (network connections/disk IO) are blocked by the OS and force close your app! So it is recommended to use AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html or theads

Answer (score 2):

Your "big process" is running on the UI thread, that is very bad. Use an `AsyncTask` for example. Show a progress view as well.